# Does an adjoint of an internal Hom functor of a prounital closed category define a tensor product?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, adjoint-operators, monoidal-categories, hom-functor

A closed category is a category equipped with internal Hom functors along with a unit object.  Now [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140842/71829) shows that if $C$ is a closed category whose internal Hom functor has a left adjoint, then this left adjoint defines a tensor product on $C$, i.e. it makes $C$ into a monoidal category.  But I’m wondering if something more general is true.

A [prounital closed category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+category#omitting_units_prounital_closed_categories) is like a closed category, except that the requirements regarding a unit object are dropped.  (I don’t think this is standard terminology.) My question is, if $C$ is a prounital closed category whose internal Hom functor has a left adjoint, then does this left adjoint define some kind of tensor product on $C$?  Now it presumably wouldn’t make $C$ monoidal, since you no longer have a unit object.  But would it at least make $C$ into a “semigroupal category”, i.e. a category with a tensor product which satisfies all the properties of a monoidal category except the requirements regarding a unit object?

If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?

Comment: Are there any examples you're interested in?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan No, I was just curious about whether the result could be generalized.